# How to build APK ready for release?

Tags: android, apk

I want to build a APK for release that needs to signed manually later by another set of people. Is it enough to remove/update android:debuggable to false and hand apk over to signing team? Or there is more needs to be done? I'm using eclipse to generate apk and hoping to see it in bin directory after building project. A stepwise explanation will be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Eclipse, right-click the project, go to `Android Tools` and choose `Export Unsigned Application Package`. Nothing more to it for you.